# nutch inject with hbase NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hbase, nutch

When I try and run nutch I am presented with the following error.  I have hbase-0.94.0 installed and running, hadoop is running also with no problems.  in ${NUTCH_HOME}/runtime/local/lib hbase-0.94.0.jar is present.  I get the following error, it does seem to be a problem with a dependency but I am quite stuck.
Thanks

```
./nutch inject /tmp/seed.txt
InjectorJob: starting
InjectorJob: urlDir: /tmp/seed.txt
2012-09-11 22:02:14.097 java[7636:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor.setMaxVersions(I)V
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseMapping$HBaseMappingBuilder.addFamilyProps(HBaseMapping.java:114)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.readMapping(HBaseStore.java:545)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:113)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:69)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:243)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:268)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:298)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with hbase-0.90.5 I guess there is a problem or some other configuration to be added when using nutch 2 and hbase-0.94.*

Comment: At this moment Gora works with hbase-0.90.4 (0.90.5). It's planned to upgrade soon (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-201)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common compatibility issue these days. We just need to wait when Apache Gora adopts Apache HBase 0.98.x or above. Meanwhile there exists a workaround described below.

Apache Nutch 2.2.1 uses Apache Gora 0.3 which only supports old Apache HBase 0.90.x.
To use Nutch 2.2.x at the moment you have to:

1. Clone, configure and build fresh [Nutch from the official Git branch 2.x](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/2.x).
2. Clone and build [my version of Apache HBase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0](https://github.com/dobromyslov/hbase/releases/tag/0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0).

You can also read [compatibility documentation for Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html) to figure out how to build your own version for any Hadoop release.

And to be completely informed take a look at the similar [issue with Apache Gora 0.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-304).

My tested working stack is:

- Apache Nutch from 2.x git branch which uses Gora 0.4;
- Apache Hbase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0;
- Apache Hadoop 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

When I run nutch2.0 with 0.94.1 in command, it's nosuchmethod, and in eclipse it's java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration.
althogh I copy jar or config classpath. it's not work.
now I will change to 90.5, I hope it going to work.